# C# Moq - Is there a way to mock only the base method and not its overridden version?

Tags: c#, mocking, overriding, moq, virtual

I know I can Mock `CreateAsync` method in this example:

```
//this abstract class is an external class in another DLL
public abstract class SomeRepository<T>
{
    public virtual Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity)
    {
        (...)
    }
}

public class MyEntity
{

}

public class MyRepository : SomeRepository<MyEntity>
{

}
```

By simply calling this code:

```
var mock = new Mock<MyRepository>();
mock.Setup(opt => opt.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<MyEntity>())).ReturnsAsync(new MyEntity());
```

But what if I have an override method inside `MyRepository`?

```
public class MyRepository : SomeRepository<MyEntity>
{
    public override Task<MyEntity> CreateAsync(MyEntity entity)
    {
        (...)
        return base.CreateAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to only mock `base.CreateAsync()` but not the new overrided method?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to only mock *part* of a class. You're either testing the class, in which case it shouldn't be mocked, or you're testing another class and need this as a dependency. Mocked dependencies should be explicit about what they return, so you are only testing the one class

Comment: Adding to the above: if you are trying to test the functionality of `MyRepository` and find yourself wanting to mock the `base.CreateAsync` method, you likely actually want to mock whatever `base.CreateAsync` is doing inside instead (probably calling some external dependency like a database or web API). If you're actually testing some other code that has a dependency on `MyRepository`, passing a mock instance of `MyRepository` (or ideally it's interface) effectively means that you don't care how it's implemented (i.e. that it calls a base method).

Comment: Correct, I want to mock whatever `base.CreateAsync` is doing because the base class is not in my current project (It's an external DLL), but the override method I wrote is. So I want to test all lines of my override method and to mock only the call to base that is not in my project. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That's a less clear scenario. What is actually being done in your overridden method?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I do some transformations to entity object before sending it to the real `CreateAsync`. If I mock CreateAsync as is, some lines of code will be missing in code coverage. I could simply change the name of my method to something else, and be done with it, but I was wondering if I could do what I asked (or if it really makes sense).

Comment: If there is a difference between your domain models and your database models, the transformation could be done in a service layer instead of directly in the repository. Then you can unit test your Service class, and mock the repository that it depends on

Comment: Does [`Callbase`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior) work for you?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thanks for the ideas, that's a good point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible with Moq. But if you change your design a little to prefer composition over inheritance, it would make it much more easier to test. 

Inject `SomeRepository<T>` and you can mock everything on that class.

And maybe make both classes Implement an interface ISomeRepository<T>, so that you can still use an abstraction to resolve `MyRepository`